# Do we say "He pretended to not know anything about it" and "He pretended not to know anything about it" in both British and American English?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

This is what I learned in grammar books. That is, the negative form of "**to bare infinitive**" is "**not to bare infinitive**".

For example, "**They hope to win the match**" and "**They hope not to lose the match**".

But some native speakers say "**They hope to not lose the match**".

Is it regional to say "**to + not + bare infinitive**" or is it correct to say that in both British and American English?

Comment: I (UK) don't find _hope to not_ or _pretend to not_ a natural usage.

Comment: They hope to not lose the match. is acceptable but awkward or requires a reason for saying it that way. And once again, this has zero to do with British versus American English. Generally we'd all say: **They hope they won't lose the match**. If you want to sound idiomatic. I keep seeing present simple in Netflix translations from German and Nordic languages because the translators are non-English speakers and don't realize you must use "will" in most cases. I go tomorrow. instead of: I'll go tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Both are acceptable.

But the second one is more common.

It is better to use   +

Comment: Can you provide proof that _hope to not_ is acceptable?